@Around is not handling Feign methods
This is my gradle.build:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'

    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '6.6.0'

}

apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'

group = 'com.berekebank.mass_credit'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.7")
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'

    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'

    implementation 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0'
    implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.6.11'
    implementation 'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.6'


    implementation('org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp:7.19.0')

    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.23.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers'

    implementation 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:5.10.1'
    implementation 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-jdbc-template:5.10.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.9.8'
    implementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.0"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'pl.allegro.finance:tradukisto:2.2.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

def passedTests = 0
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty 'profile', System.getProperty('profile', 'test')
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        if (result.resultType == TestResult.ResultType.SUCCESS) {
            println "Test passed: ${desc.className}.${desc.name}"
            passedTests++
        }
    }
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
        println "TOTAL TESTS PASSED: $passedTests"
    }

}

I have next feign client which contain method that will be called from service:
package com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration;

import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.consts.HeaderConst;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.exception.handling.ReqExceptionHandledBy;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.exception.handling.impl.QpragmaRequestExceptionHandler;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.interceptor.RequestHeaderInterceptor;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.model.history.RequestHistoryType;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.annotation.IntegrationRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.request.*;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.response.*;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.UUID;

@FeignClient(name = "integration-service", configuration = RequestHeaderInterceptor.class)
public interface IntegrationMicroService {

    @Description("Получение инфо о клиенте")
    @IntegrationRequest(RequestHistoryType.INTEGRATION)
    @ReqExceptionHandledBy(QpragmaRequestExceptionHandler.class)
    @RequestMapping(path = "/clients/{bin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    CustomerDetailedInfoResponse getCustomerInfo(@RequestHeader(HeaderConst.APPLICATION_ID) UUID applicationId,
                                                 @PathVariable(name = "bin") final String bin);
}

This is aspect class that should handle every callings from Feign and write some historical data to DB:
package com.berekebank.post_loan_service.aop;

import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.exception.handling.ReqExceptionHandledBy;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.exception.handling.RequestExceptionHandler;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.model.history.CreateReqHistoryDto;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.model.history.RequestHistoryType;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.annotation.IntegrationRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.service.history.RequestHistoryService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Component
@Aspect
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IntegrationLoggingAspect {

    private final RequestHistoryService requestHistoryService;

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Around("execution(* com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.IntegrationMicroService.*(*))")
    public Object aroundMethodExecutionIntegration(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return handleMethodCall(joinPoint);
    }

    private Object handleMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        String description = Optional.ofNullable(method.getAnnotation(Description.class))
                .map(Description::value)
                .orElse("Description not found");

        RequestHistoryType requestType = Optional.ofNullable(method.getAnnotation(IntegrationRequest.class))
                .map(IntegrationRequest::value)
                .orElse(RequestHistoryType.INTEGRATION);

        if (RequestHistoryType.IGNORED == requestType) {
            return handleIgnoredIntegrationRequests(joinPoint);
        }

        RequestExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = Optional.ofNullable(method.getAnnotation(ReqExceptionHandledBy.class))
                .map(ReqExceptionHandledBy::value)
                .map(applicationContext::getBean)
                .orElse(null);

        var applicationId = applicationId(joinPoint.getArgs(), signature.getParameterNames());
        var requestId = requestId(joinPoint.getArgs(), signature.getParameterNames());
    
        var createReqHistory = CreateReqHistoryDto.builder()
                .applicationId(applicationId)
                .requestId(requestId)
                .methodName(method.getName())
                .description(description)
                .args(joinPoint.getArgs())
                .type(requestType)
                .build();

        var id = requestHistoryService.beforeMethodInvocation(createReqHistory);

        Object res;

        try {
            res = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (exceptionHandler != null && exceptionHandler.canHandle(e)) {
                exceptionHandler.handle(e, applicationId);
                requestHistoryService.onException(id, e);
            } else {
                requestHistoryService.onException(id, applicationId, e);
            }

            throw e;
        }

        requestHistoryService.onSuccess(id, res);

        return res;
    }

    private UUID applicationId(Object[] args, String[] parameterNames) {
        return getHeaderValue(args, parameterNames, "applicationId");
    }

    private UUID requestId(Object[] args, String[] parameterNames) {
        return getHeaderValue(args, parameterNames, "requestId");
    }

    private UUID getHeaderValue(Object[] args, String[] parameterNames, String headerName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
            if (headerName.equals(parameterNames[i]) && args[i] instanceof UUID result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Object handleIgnoredIntegrationRequests(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

}

And I am calling this method from feign here in my service class:
package com.berekebank.post_loan_service.service.postLoan;

import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.camunda.model.ChangeDecisionValues;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.camunda.model.MutableCreatePostLoan;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.consts.CamundaConst;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.consts.PGConsts;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.controller.model.CreateRestructureRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.controller.model.SendDocsRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.controller.model.SendStatusRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.controller.model.UpdateRestructureStatusRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.controller.model.enums.IntegrationStatus;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.controller.model.enums.RestructureStatus;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.converter.ApplicationConverter;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.converter.ApplicationDocConverter;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.converter.ApplicationStatusConverter;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.converter.RestructureConverter;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.converter.request_builder.RestructureDocRequestBuilder;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.converter.request_builder.RestructureRequestBuilder;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.exception.*;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.model.notification.NotificationDto;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.CrudDataService;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.PostgresSequenceRepository;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.bBusiness.BBusinessLoanService;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.IntegrationMicroService;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.request.CancelRestructureRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.request.GetLoanInfoRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.request.RestructureLoanRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.request.ValidateLoanRequest;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.response.CustomerDetailedInfoResponse;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.response.LoanInfoResponse;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.api.integration.model.response.RestructureCancelResponse;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.entity.camunda.ProcessInstanceEntity;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.repository.entity.restructure.*;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.service.notificaiton.NotificationService;
import com.berekebank.post_loan_service.util.RestructureIdUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import static com.berekebank.post_loan_service.consts.RestructureSignDocConsts.Agreement.HEAD;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestructureServiceImpl implements RestructureService {

    private final CrudDataService<RestructureApplicationEntity> applicationRepository;
    private final CrudDataService<ProcessInstanceEntity> processInstanceRepository;
    private final PostgresSequenceRepository postgresSequenceRepository;

    private final RuntimeService runtimeService;
    private final IntegrationMicroService integrationService;
    private final BBusinessLoanService bBusinessLoanService;
    private final InvalidationService invalidationService;
    private final RestructureCancelService restructureCancelService;
    private final NotificationService notificationService;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final Clock clock;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    @Override
    public void generateNaturalId(String applicationId) {
        RestructureApplicationEntity application = applicationRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(applicationId))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ApplicationNotFoundException(applicationId));

        CustomerDetailedInfoResponse customerInfo = integrationService.getCustomerInfo(application.getId(), application.getBin());

        var seqValue = postgresSequenceRepository.nextVal(PGConsts.RESTRUCTURE_NATURAL_ID_SEQ);

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(clock);
        var identifier = RestructureIdUtils.generateNaturalId(today, seqValue, customerInfo.branchId());

        CustomerDetailedInfoResponse.Person headPerson = customerInfo.persons().stream()
                .filter(person -> person.type().contains(HEAD)).findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new DocumentBuildException("uW6BPIzqDCj :: not found head of company"));
        String fullName = String.format("%s %s %s", headPerson.lastName(), headPerson.name(), headPerson.patron());
        String orgFormFullKaz = String.format("%s %s", RestructureDocRequestBuilder.getOrgFormShortKaz(customerInfo.orgForm()), customerInfo.name());

        application.setNaturalId(identifier);
        application.setOrganizationName(orgFormFullKaz);
        application.setUserFullName(fullName);

        applicationRepository.update(application);
    }
 }

But method aroundMethodExecutionIntegration() is not working. It is just ignoring feign method. How to solve this problem?

Use (..) instead of (*). .. means 0 or more arguments whereas * means exactly 1 and your method has 2 arguments.
